# Parcelize Kotlin (org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

This is my data class which is extending `Parcelable` and annotation with `@Parcelize`

```
@Parcelize
data class MusicTrack(
    val id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val albumId: String,
    val artist: String,
    val duration: String,
    val trackArt: String = "",
    val fileUri: Uri) : Parcelable
```

Then I try to put this in a bundle to send across

```
override fun playTrack(position: Int, musicList: ArrayList<MusicTrack>) {
    info { musicList }
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList(Config.MusicConfig.MUSIC_TRACKS, musicList)
    bundle.putInt(Config.MusicConfig.MUSIC_TRACK_POSITION, position)
    MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(this).transportControls.playFromUri(Uri.parse("Hack"), bundle)
}
```

Consuming the bundle

```
  override fun onPlayFromUri(uri: Uri?, extras: Bundle?) {
        super.onPlayFromUri(uri, extras)

        val bundle = extras

        info {
            bundle?.get(Config.MusicConfig.MUSIC_TRACKS)
            bundle?.get(Config.MusicConfig.MUSIC_TRACK_POSITION)
        }
    }
```

Throws

```
android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling:
```

Comment: Have you added `androidExtensions { experimental = true }` to your build.gradle?

Comment: it's probably the `val fileUri: Uri` that causes trouble

Comment: I've added androidExtensions as true. How does Uri affect this?